Finding Jacobian from Hamiltonian
Suppose I am given a Hamiltonian. How do I find the Jacobian from the Hamilton equations of motion? Here is what I have done so far:
coordrep = {t -> t[\[Tau]], 
   r -> r[\[Tau]], \[Theta] -> \[Theta][\[Tau]], \[Phi] -> \[Phi][\
\[Tau]], t' -> t'[\[Tau]], 
   r' -> r'[\[Tau]], \[Theta]' -> \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]};
lagrangian = -1/(
    2 \[Pi] \[Alpha]) (f[r] t'^2 - r'^2/f[r] - r^2 \[Theta]'^2 + 
      r^2 n^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) /. coordrep;
Pt = D[lagrangian, t'[\[Tau]]];
Pr = D[lagrangian, r'[\[Tau]]];
P\[Theta] = D[lagrangian, \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]];
hamiltonian = ((Pt t'[\[Tau]] + Pr r'[\[Tau]] + 
        P\[Theta] \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]) - 
      lagrangian) /. (Solve[{pt[\[Tau]] == Pt, pr[\[Tau]] == Pr, 
        p\[Theta][\[Tau]] == P\[Theta]}, {t'[\[Tau]], 
        r'[\[Tau]], \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]}] // Last) // Simplify;
equations = {t'[\[Tau]] == D[hamiltonian, pt[\[Tau]]], 
  r'[\[Tau]] == D[hamiltonian, pr[\[Tau]]], \[Theta]'[\[Tau]] == 
   D[hamiltonian, p\[Theta][\[Tau]]], 
  pt'[\[Tau]] == -D[hamiltonian, t[\[Tau]]], 
  pr'[\[Tau]] == -D[hamiltonian, r[\[Tau]]], 
  p\[Theta]'[\[Tau]] == -D[hamiltonian, \[Theta][\[Tau]]]}
f[r_] = 1 - (2 M)/r + Q^2/r^2 + r^2/l^2;
M = 1/2; \[Alpha] = 1/\[Pi]; n = 1;

I was able to find the equations of motion. How should I proceed to find the Jacobian of the given system? Any help in this regard would be truly beneficial!

Based on your code:
(* Your original code *)
coordrep = {t -> t[\[Tau]], 
   r -> r[\[Tau]], \[Theta] -> \[Theta][\[Tau]], \[Phi] -> \[Phi][\
\[Tau]], t' -> t'[\[Tau]], 
   r' -> r'[\[Tau]], \[Theta]' -> \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]};
lagrangian = -1/(
    2 \[Pi] \[Alpha]) (f[r] t'^2 - r'^2/f[r] - r^2 \[Theta]'^2 + 
      r^2 n^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) /. coordrep;
Pt = D[lagrangian, t'[\[Tau]]];
Pr = D[lagrangian, r'[\[Tau]]];
P\[Theta] = D[lagrangian, \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]];
hamiltonian = ((Pt t'[\[Tau]] + Pr r'[\[Tau]] + 
        P\[Theta] \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]) - 
      lagrangian) /. (Solve[{pt[\[Tau]] == Pt, pr[\[Tau]] == Pr, 
        p\[Theta][\[Tau]] == P\[Theta]}, {t'[\[Tau]], 
        r'[\[Tau]], \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]}] // Last) // Simplify;
equations = {t'[\[Tau]] == D[hamiltonian, pt[\[Tau]]], 
  r'[\[Tau]] == D[hamiltonian, pr[\[Tau]]], \[Theta]'[\[Tau]] == 
   D[hamiltonian, p\[Theta][\[Tau]]], 
  pt'[\[Tau]] == -D[hamiltonian, t[\[Tau]]], 
  pr'[\[Tau]] == -D[hamiltonian, r[\[Tau]]], 
  p\[Theta]'[\[Tau]] == -D[hamiltonian, \[Theta][\[Tau]]]}
f[r_] = 1 - (2 M)/r + Q^2/r^2 + r^2/l^2;
M = 1/2; \[Alpha] = 1/\[Pi]; n = 1;

Jacobian definition:
If you mean, the Jacobian defined as,
$$
   J = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial p_i \partial q_j} & \frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial p_i \partial p_j} \\ -\frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial q_i \partial q_j} & -\frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial q_i \partial p_j} \end{bmatrix}
$$
To find the Jacobian, you need to compute the second derivatives of the Hamiltonian with respect to the coordinates $q_i$ and momenta $p_i$.
In Wolfram code:
Here’s how I would proceed with computing the Jacobian matrix for your Hamiltonian:
(*Define the variables and Hamiltonian*)
q = {t[\[Tau]], r[\[Tau]], \[Theta][\[Tau]]};
p = {pt[\[Tau]], pr[\[Tau]], p\[Theta][\[Tau]]};

(*Compute the second derivatives to form the Jacobian matrix*)
jacobianMatrix = {D[hamiltonian, {p, 1}, {q, 1}], 
   D[hamiltonian, {p, 2}], -D[hamiltonian, {q, 2}], -D[
     hamiltonian, {q, 1}, {p, 1}]};

(*Simplify the Jacobian if needed*)
jacobianMatrix = Simplify[jacobianMatrix] // FullSimplify

With the solution the following matrix:
{{{0, (pt[\[Tau]] (-((2 Q^2)/r[\[Tau]]^3) + 1/r[\[Tau]]^2 + (
      2 r[\[Tau]])/l^2))/(1 + (Q^2 - r[\[Tau]] + r[\[Tau]]^4/l^2)/
     r[\[Tau]]^2)^2, 0}, {0, (
   pr[\[Tau]] (-2 Q^2 + r[\[Tau]] + (2 r[\[Tau]]^4)/l^2))/r[\[Tau]]^3,
    0}, {0, -((2 p\[Theta][\[Tau]])/r[\[Tau]]^3), 
   0}}, {{-(1/(1 + (Q^2 - r[\[Tau]] + r[\[Tau]]^4/l^2)/r[\[Tau]]^2)), 
   0, 0}, {0, 1 + (Q^2 - r[\[Tau]] + r[\[Tau]]^4/l^2)/r[\[Tau]]^2, 
   0}, {0, 0, 1/r[\[Tau]]^2}}, {{0, 0, 
   0}, {0, -((3 p\[Theta][\[Tau]]^2)/r[\[Tau]]^4) + 
    pr[\[Tau]]^2 (-(1/l^2) + (-3 Q^2 + r[\[Tau]])/r[\[Tau]]^4) + (
    l^2 pt[\[Tau]]^2 (l^4 Q^4 + 
       r[\[Tau]]^2 (-3 l^4 Q^2 + 
          r[\[Tau]] (l^4 - 12 l^2 Q^2 r[\[Tau]] + 6 l^2 r[\[Tau]]^2 - 
             l^2 r[\[Tau]]^3 + 3 r[\[Tau]]^5))))/(l^2 Q^2 - 
      l^2 r[\[Tau]] + l^2 r[\[Tau]]^2 + r[\[Tau]]^4)^3 - 
    Sin[\[Theta][\[Tau]]]^2, -r[\[Tau]] Sin[
     2 \[Theta][\[Tau]]]}, {0, -r[\[Tau]] Sin[
     2 \[Theta][\[Tau]]], -Cos[2 \[Theta][\[Tau]]] r[\[Tau]]^2}}, {{0,
    0, 0}, {-((
    pt[\[Tau]] (-((2 Q^2)/r[\[Tau]]^3) + 1/r[\[Tau]]^2 + (
       2 r[\[Tau]])/l^2))/(1 + (Q^2 - r[\[Tau]] + r[\[Tau]]^4/l^2)/
      r[\[Tau]]^2)^2), -pr[\[Tau]] (-((2 Q^2)/r[\[Tau]]^3) + 1/
      r[\[Tau]]^2 + (2 r[\[Tau]])/l^2), (2 p\[Theta][\[Tau]])/
   r[\[Tau]]^3}, {0, 0, 0}}}

I suggest you check if this is what you are looking for.
